# typescript compile on save breaks AngularJS in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, tsc

I have a Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.2) project with AngularJS 1.6.5 and a NancyFX server.

Code here:

https://github.com/GusBeare/NancyAngularTests

This is a playground for me to learn and test features I'd like to use on a real project.

All the AngularJS stuff is in Typescript files and my tsconfig.json tells the compiler to compile it all into a single JS file `Content/js/bundle.js`.

When I build and run the project everything works as expected and there are no issues.  However, if I edit a .ts file while the app is running it breaks with this error:

```
angular.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=mySPA
```

The compile on save seems to work fine since the `Content/js/bundle.js` is rebuilt on save. But why do I get the Angular error only on compile on save?

Am I doing something wrong in my AngularJS code or is this a Typescript/Visual Studio thing?

If I build and publish the project it runs fine under IIS and I can't break it.

Comment: I believe this is something to do with the ordering of the code that is bundled into bundle.js.  When I build the project in VS the order of files in tsconfig.json is honored. However, when I run the project and edit + save  a .ts file with the "compileonSave" option set to true the order of the code bundled changes to some other order which breaks it.

Comment: If I can find the time I'll try a different bundling method.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that outside of VS if I compiled the typescript using tsc then the order of files in my tsconfig.json was honored so I assumed a bug in the VS typescript tools.

So I went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 and noticed a new version had just been released (2.4.1).

Installing this fixed the issue for me. The ts compiler now reads the files in the specified order and bundles them correctly.

**Update**:

No I was mistaken. It's not fixed.  If I build the project then it fails to run because it does not honor the files compile order.  However, when I edit the bundle directly and change the order and then further edit .ts files then bundle.js is rebuilt correctly. But if I close the project again and build it's incorrect.  tsc still works on the command line to bundle in the correct order.
This is all terribly buggy.

**Update 2**

As a work around I converted app.js back to JS and moved it out of the ts bundle. This is now loaded first before bundle.js and everything works fine.